# Tracking Down a Datasheet for an unknown Optical Sensor

Tags: sensor, integrated-circuit, identification, datasheet, image-sensor

I scavenged an optical sensor out of a wireless mouse I had, and now I'm trying to track down the data sheet.  Honestly, the pinout (from what I could determine looking at the board in which it was soldered) seems pretty similar to a "ADNS2620" (like this one at sparkfun: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/12907) but I'd like to track down a data sheet to make the process of figuring it out a little easier.  Pictures provided below, direction helpful.

[image: optical_sensor_top]

[image: optical_sensor_bottom]

For those curious, the text appears to say "FCT3065-XY" and "16365A6".

Comment: The AVAGO ADNS2620 data sheet might be a good start - these chips often have I2C serial interface, and require a 24 MHz ceramic resonator. Compare Avago's data sheet schematic with the mouse circuit from which you pulled the chip.

Comment: Yeah, as I look the pinout (compared to how it was soldered in the board) seem identical - but curiously, neither of the cheap mice (from which I've pulled very similar optical sensors) have had anything at all soldered to the oscillator pins.

Comment: In a multimeter do-everything-chip, have seen a clone *optimize out* the oscillator, where the original had a crystal. Shouldn't be hard to add a high-frequency oscillator entirely on-chip, for cost-sensitive high-volume production, like mouses. If the other pins are similar to Avago's - try talking I2C to/from it anyway.

Comment: Avago is now Broadcom on sensors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid all I have is bad news.  Logitech uses the FCT3065-XY in their mice, so I contacted Logitec to see if they knew where to get the datasheet.  Their response is that they won't release the information because it's "Logitech Proprietary."

Comment: You went above and beyond to help me out, and I appreciate it.  I'll make it work one was or another.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Sensors]

I was able to find this online, now assuming this stands true, that would mean the FCT3065-XY should be identical to the FCT3065, which led me to find this: https://octopart.com/fct3065-pixart-84957100 . According to the site it should be a PixArt sensor but the specs are unknown.

I do have a mouse with that sensor, and it has a DPI range of 800-2000, and seemingly if you searched for mice with PixArt 3065, most of them have DPI ranges around that.

Comment: Wow, that's some excellent sleuthing!  I ended up tinkering at it with an o-scope for a while and found that it seemed to use a protocol similar to that in some pixart sensors, but I never got it working fully.  Thanks!